# How do I filter this LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I got a query that I want to filter out some values stored in an array of string.

Query:

```
public IQueryable<ProductModel> GetProductQuery()
{
   var query = from product in DataContext.tProduct
               select new ProductModel() {
                  ProductId = product.ProductId,
                  ProductName = product.ProductName,
                  Categories = product.tLinkProductCategory.Select(c => new CategoryModel
                  {
                     CategoryID = c.tCategory.CategoryId,
                     CategoryName = c.tCategory.CategoryName
                  })
               };
   string[] categories = new[] {"A", "B"};
   query = query.Where(c => categories.Contains(c.Categories.CategoryName..)) //??
   return query;
}
```

Can I solve this with .Contains?

Comment: You can. But you should give more info, e.g. what is the expected result, what are you currently getting, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Hari Prasad is right about `Any`, but the correct query is:

```
query = query.Where(p => p.Categories.Any(c => categories.Contains(c.CategoryName));
```

Answer (score 2):

Using  `Any` `Linq` extension you could achieve this.

```
 query = query.Where(c => categories.Any(x=> x == c.Categories.CategoryName));
```

Given a choice , I prefer using `HastSet` over string array, which allows an O(1) access. You might see big performance improvement when the size grows bigger.

```
 HashSet<string> categories  = new HashSet<int>(); 
 query = query.Where(c => categories.Contain(c.Categories.CategoryName));
```